# Struggle trying to simplify code

Tags: haskell

I have the following methods:

```
mainFunction arg1 = "http://someBaseUrl.com/" ++ arg1
url1 x = mainFunction x ++ "/subUrl1"
url2 x = mainFunction x ++ "/subUrl2"
url3 x = mainFunction x ++ "/subUrl3"
url4 x = mainFunction x ++ "/subUrl4"
```

My gut tells me that it has to be simplified. But I can't figure out how.

I can't do this, though, because it's not the same:

```
url1 = (mainFunction .) ++ "/subUrl1"
```

Your suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
url s x = mainFunction x ++ s
url1 = url "/subUrl1"
url2 = url "/subUrl2"
```

etc ...

If you really to write as less code as possible and avoid to call `url` tree times, you can use this trick (however, I'm not sure it is recommended)

```
[url1, url2, url3, url4] = map url ["/subUrl1", "/subUrl2", "subUrl3", "subUrl4"]
```

This will declare the four functions `url1`, ... `url4`.

Comment: what's the argument "s"?

Comment: and why do you call "url" with only one argument?

Comment: `s` is your suburl. I call it only with one argument because the 2nd one is not needed. I could write `url1 x = url "/subUrl1" x` which similar to what you written,  but in that case, it's  equivalent to `url1  = url "/subUrl1"` (you can remove the x on both side). That's called partial application

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using a single function with two arguments?

```hs
url :: (Show a) => String -> a -> String
url x n = "www" ++ x ++ "/vvv" ++ show n
```

You should also use `Text` when dealing with URLs and unicode in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings to make your URL.  To convert a non-string value to a string, you can use `show` if it is an instance of Show.

```
url a b = "http://someBaseUrl.com/" ++ a ++ "/subUrl" ++ (show b)
```

The url function takes a "string" (list of chars) [Char] and another type 'a' (which is also an instance of Show) and returns a new "string".

```
Prelude> let url a b = "http://someBaseUrl.com/" ++ a ++ "/subUrl" ++ (show b)
Prelude> url "foo" 3
"http://someBaseUrl.com/foo/subUrl3"
Prelude> :t url
url :: Show a => [Char] -> a -> [Char]
```