# Is parallel declaration of function a good idea?

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming

Answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24586456/376113), I realized that `Haskell` allows you to *deconstruct* object when declaring function and use it to do parallel function definitions.

Basically, let's imagine I would like to do something like this

```
 a = (1+)
 b = (2+)
 c = (3+)
 d = (4+)
 e = (5+)
```

What would be the DRYest way to write it ? I mean, after all the pattern is the same: The name of function can't be guessed neither the amount to add, but I should be able to avoid to write `+` every time (without using Template Haskell of course).

Basically, I would like to be able to use `map` or something similar and It appears that `map` just works!.

```
[a,b,c,d,e] = map (+) [1..5]
```

Et voila !

That's much shorter and maybe more expressive, and it works :

```
> a 10
11
> b 10
12
etc ...
```

So my question is , is it a good pattern to use (in that kind of situation) and if not, which are the draw backs (I know buy experience that the equivalent in **Ruby** is a nightmare, but the reasons doesn't seems to apply with Haskell)?

## Update

I understand the *readability* of such code is subjective and can be seen as opinion-based. However, there might be some objective reasons to not do it. For example, in **Ruby** (1.8 at least), methods defined using `define_method`  are invisible to most IDEs and tags builder. Moreover, you can't step into them using the debugger  etc... which make them really unconvenient in practice. I'm asking for similar reason in **Haskell**

Comment: This question is attracting "Primarily opinion-based" close votes - although I think there is a degree of subjectivity in the question, it's still capable of a reasonably objective answer and should be left open.

Answer (score 8):

One downside with

```
[a,b,c,d,e] = map (+) [1..5]
```

is that it requires non-exhaustive pattern-matching - the match isn't statically guaranteed to be valid. Obviously in this case there's no problem, but in a more subtle example where perhaps `[1..5]` was defined elsewhere, it might be harder to see.

I also don't see any particular advantage to this style in this particular case, though I realise it is a bit of a contrived example.

One case where defining multiple values in a single line is worthwhile is if you have a function that returns a tuple, e.g:

```
(xs, ys) = unzip [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

Comment: The non-exhaustive mess could be partially solved by writing `a:b:c:d:e:_ = map (+) [1..]`

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished using the package for [homogeneous tuples](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuples-homogenous-h98) (which I'm the author of):

```
import Data.Tuple.Homogenous

...
  let Tuple4 (a, b, c, d) = fmap (+) $ Tuple4 (1, 2, 3, 4)
   in ...
```

without resorting to non-exhaustive pattern matching.

Also there is another similar package [tup-functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tup-functor).